# Cannot Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library - "Not an App Engine project"

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

When I attempt to generate an endpoint client library in Eclipse (GPE 3.5.1, GAE SDK 1.9.4) I get this error: "Not an App Engine project". The project *is* an App Engine project (and is deployed). The project is configured as an EAR project with backend and frontend modules. I don't get any errors in the Error Log.

GAE SDK 1.9.3 gives me the same error. I've also tried the command line but simply get 'Error'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your your cloud-endpoints projects using WTP, then Right click on the "cloud-endpoints" project => "**Google App Engine WTP**" => "Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library"

You get the error if you right click on the "cloud-endpoints" project => "Google" => "Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library".

If you do not see the "**Google App Engine WTP**" menu item, ensure you are using the Java EE perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You need create firts  app engine project, then in that prject generate  the library  for  you cliens.