# Google App Engine - Not an app engine project

Tags: eclipse

I've got a GAE project set up in Eclipse that I can deploy and run on a local app engine server.  Now I'm trying to add cloud endpoints and when I choose to "Generate Cloud Endpoint Class" with one of my simple Java classes I immediately get the pop-up error "Not an app engine project".

I do have a proper application id set up in appengine-web.xml and registered online.  The error happens immediately so I don't think there is even any checking being doe in the cloud.  It would seem it has something to do with the project structure.

Something I notice that is odd is that when I right click on the source file the Google menu has "Generate Cloud Endpoint Class" enabled but the "Google App Engine WTP" menu has the same option to "Generate Cloud Endpoint Class" but it is gray.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is eclipse problem not google-app-engine

Comment: What project type did you select when you created the project? There may also be some useful info in the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752398/cannot-generate-cloud-endpoint-client-library-not-an-app-engine-project and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128512/is-it-possible-to-use-appengine-modules-and-and-cloud-endpoints.